# How to format paragraph long string within android.widget.TextView so that lines are even?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am writing an About page and I get a long paragraph back. I put it in TextView and it looks like the following

```
     AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
     AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
     AAAAAAAAAAA.  AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
     AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA.
```

Is there any way to get it to format so that lines are somewhat even?

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain it better? what do you mean by "even"? You mean to justify?

Comment: you can write html format and set html string in textView

Comment: yeah justify.  Its even on the left but the right there is just too much variance on end of line position, and when the line wraps as well it is just not even close to even.

Comment: How would one use html format?  I do have an html <p> paragram </p> but it ends up showing the </p> so I use Html.fromHtml(txt) but then I don't have html formatting.

Comment: you can not justify text in textview.. so you have to use webview.... that i have given in answer

Comment: you can format your paragraph with html and use it as i have shown in example.I hope it will be helpful!

Answer (score 0):

i have also same problem ... ao i have used WebView instead of TextView and .. i have load data like.

```
webview.loadDataWithBaseURL(null,"<head><style>* {margin:0;padding:0;font-size:15; text-align:justify}</style></head>"+YOUR TEXT),"text/html","UTF-8","about:blank");
```

so you can have justify text in your webview.

Answer (score 0):

in your strings.xml,define a string containing that paragraph,

e.g.

```
    <string name="longtext">
   <![CDATA[
    <html><body><p style="text-align:justify">
    your paragraph text
   </p></body></html>]]>
   </string>
```

and set this text in your textview by using ,

```
    tvTemp.setText(Html.fromHtml(getResources().getString(R.string.longtext)));
```